# What does this matlab statement do

Tags: matlab, function, handle

I have a statement in my MATLAB program:

```
f = @(A)DistanceGauss(A,x_axis,Y_target,Y_initial,numOf,modus);
```

I understood that `f` is defined as the function handle to the function `distancegauss` which contains the parameters/arg list present inside the parentheses.

What does the variable `A` in `@(A)` do? Does it have any importance? While browsing I found that the variables within parentheses after `@` would be the input arguments for an anonymous function..

Can anyone explain what does that `A` do?  Will this handle work even without that `A` after the `@` symbol ? Because it is already present as an argument to be passed after the function name.

Comment: `A` is just a variable, exactly as `x` would be when you define usual functions (like `f : x --> x^2`). Your declaration means that `f` is an anonymous function that takes an input `A` and applies `DistanceGauss(A,x_axis,Y_target,Y_initial,numOf,modus);` to it.

Comment: Your matlab program? Then surely you know what it does. If not, who wrote the code? Have you considered asking them? Have you considered learning how an anonymous function works, since you've figured out that's what you're facing?

Comment: In your case, the `@(A)` means that when calling `f`, only the first parameter of `DistanceGauss` is variable and the rest are held constant (to the values that they were when you defined `f`)

Comment: If your issue is resolved, please accept the answer (by clicking on the tick mark on the left side) or enter your own answer that worked for you instead. This way others know you are not still looking for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous function should be defined such as:

```
sqr = @(x) x.^2;
```

in which `x` shows the variable of the the function and there is no name for it (it is called anonymous!).

Although you can do something like this:

```
c = 10;
mygrid = @(x,y) ndgrid((-x:x/c:x),(-y:y/c:y));
[x,y] = mygrid(pi,2*pi);
```

in which you are modifying an existing function `ndgrid` to make a new anonymous function.

In your case also:

```
f = @(A)DistanceGauss(A,x_axis,Y_target,Y_initial,numOf,modus);
```

This is a new anonymous function by modifying the function `DistanceGauss` that you may want to have a single variable `A`.

If you remove `(A)` from the code, then `f` would be a handle to the existing function `DistanceGauss`:

```
f = @DistanceGauss;
```

Now you can evaluate the function simply by using the handle:

```
f(A,x_axis,...)
```

Comment: The last part of your answer is wrong. You must always have () after the @ in an anonymous function. f = @DistanceGauss... will just give an error. You can do f=@()... then just call f with no inputs or f=@(A,x_axis,Y_target ...) if you want to input all the values.

Comment: @nivag the last part is not anonymous anymore: test this: `h = @ones;
a = h()`

Comment: Yes, but you can't do h=@ones(x); h(x); which is what you are implying in your answer. h=@ones is the same as h=@()ones;

Answer (score 0):

Your code will create an anonymous function `f` which accepts one input `A`. In particular `f` will call the function `DistanceGauss(A,x_axis,Y_target,Y_initial,numOf,modus);` where the value of `A` is whatever you input with `f(A)` and the other inputs must already exist in your workspace and will be passed to the function. Note: if the other variables don't exist you should get an error when calling `f`.

Now a reasonable question is why would you want to do this you could just call `DistanceGauss(A,x_axis,Y_target,Y_initial,numOf,modus);` directly with whatever values you want, without having to worry about whether some of them exist.

There are two main reasons I can think of why you would do this (I'm sure there are others). Firstly for simplicity where your other inputs don't change and you don't want to have to keep retyping them or have users accidentally change them.

The other reason where you would want this is when optimizing/minimizing a function, for example with [fminsearch](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminsearch.html). The matlab optimization functions will vary all inputs. If you want only vary some of them you can use this sort of syntax to reduce the number of input variables.

As to what `A` actually is in your case this will depend on what it does in `DistanceGauss`, which is not a standard MATLAB function so I suggest you look at the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

"f(**A**)" or "f of **A**" or "The function of **A**" here has the handle "**f**"
`DistanceGauss()` here is another function that was defined elsewhere in your code.

You would set `x_axis, Y_target, Y_initial, numOf, & modus` before creating the function **f**. These arguments would stay the same for Function **f**, even if you try and set them again later. 
'**A**' though, is different. You don't set it before you make the function. You can later operate on all values of **A**, such as if you plot the function or get the integral of the function. In that case, it would be performing the DistanceGauss function on every value of '**A**', (though we can't see here what `DistanceGauss` function does. )